# Reactjs - Building form from data set, FormElement not returning to the render function

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am dynamically building a form based on the state build in the constructor. I am having success building the outer html but the inner form html is not rendering. cAN SOMEONE POINT OUT WHAT i AM DOING WRONG HERE?

```
class Forms extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            enrollment: {
                class: "form-style",
                fieldsets: [{
                    id: "1",
                    title: "Company Enrollment Form",
                    formElements: [{
                        label: "Company Name:",
                        element: "input",
                        type: "text",
                        class: "",
                        name: "cName",
                        placeholder: "Your Company's Name *",
                        required: true,
                        disabled: false
                    }, {
                        label: "Company Type:",
                        element: "select",
                        type: "populateDDL",
                        class: "",
                        name: "sltCompanyType",
                        placeholder: "",
                        required: true,
                        disabled: false
                    }]
                }]
            }
        }
    }

    render() {
        let Content = null;
        if (this.props.type === "enrollment") {
            Content = <EnrollmentForm state={this.state.enrollment} />
        } else if (this.props.type === "contact") {
            Content = <ContactUsForm />
        } else {
            Content = <fourOhFour />
        }
        return (
            <div className="container formContent">
                {Content}
            </div>
        );
    }
};

function EnrollmentForm(form) {
    function renderFieldsets(fieldsets) {
        if (fieldsets.length > 0) {
            return fieldsets.map((fieldset, index) => (
                <Fieldset key={index} set={fieldset} />
            ));
        }
        else return [];
    }
    function renderFormElements(formElements) {
        if (formElements.length > 0) {
            return formElements.map((formElement, i) => (
                <FormElement key={i} set={formElement} />
            ));
        }
        else return [];
    }
    const FormElement = (props, index) => {
        console.log(props);
        /* ^^^ NOT APPEARING/LOGGING IN THE CONSOLE ^^^ */
        if (props.tag === "input") {
            return (
                <input key={index} name={props.name} />
            );
        }else if (props.tag === "select") {
            return (
                <select key={index} />
            );
        }
    };
    const Fieldset = (props, index) => {
        const elements = renderFormElements(props.set.formElements);
        return (
            <fieldset key={index}>
                <legend>
                    <span className="number fa fa-address-card"></span>
                    {props.set.title}
                </legend>
            </fieldset>
        );
    };
    const fieldsets = renderFieldsets(form.state.fieldsets);
    return (
        <form className={form.state.class}>
            {fieldsets}
        </form>
    );
}
```

The FormElement variable is not returning the html... I need to return a different type of html element based on what the tag is in the data model. In the code I have successfully created the outer fieldset but when I go to insert the html elements inside the fieldset, it doesn't do anything. I put a console.log in the code block but apparently even when I try to use the "FormElement" the code isn't firing ...

Comment: I'm lost at `function EnrollmentForm(form) {...` Why don't you just declare the different es6 classes using the the class ClassName syntax? I think that's the issue.

Comment: Can you guide me on what that looks like?

Comment: For example using **Fieldset** `class Fieldset extends React.Component { ... }`,  like you have for your Forms class. What you have setup looks like FormComponent is a function which contains different classes. It looks like you're trying to use FormComponent as a class as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have bugs in your code.

Your `FormElement` should look like

```
const FormElement = (props, index) => {
      console.log(props);
      /* ^^^ NOT APPEARING/LOGGING IN THE CONSOLE ^^^ */
      if (props.set.element === "input") {//changed from props.tags--  1
          return (
              <input key={index} name={props.name} />
          );
      }else if (props.set.element === "select") {//changed from props.tags --1
          return (
              <select key={index} />
          );
      }
      return <div>Something which is not select or input</div>; //added a fallback return. --1
  };
```

The bugs that were fixed above are:

(1) `props.tags` changed to `props.set.element`. There was no tags component in the props. So none of the if blocks were being rendered and this led to the component not returning anything. This led to an error that said

> FormElement(...): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.

This was resolved by adding the fallback return statement (2).

Your `FieldSets` should look like

```
const Fieldset = (props, index) => {
      const elements = renderFormElements(props.set.formElements);
      return (
          <fieldset key={index}>
              <legend>
                  <span className="number fa fa-address-card"></span>
                  {props.set.title}
              </legend>
              <div>{elements}</div> // consumed the elements that was created in renderFormElements.
          </fieldset>
      );
  };
```

The `elements` variable was never used in render, which led to no FormElements showing up. That was the only error fixed in the above code.

I would suggest cleaning up your code by

1. Converting `EnrollmentForm` to a class.
2. Moving `FieldSet` and `FormElement` to seperate classes or at least funtional components

That would make the logic a lot easier to debug in future.

Comment: GEEEEZZZZ... It IS Friday... Nice catch on that... Thank you!!! BTW I typically move everything out to classes after I finish the prototype otherwise I end up with a bunch of classes I am too afraid to delele LOL.

Comment: If you have time could you elaborate on what the bugs actually are doing to cause the stink? Thanks in advance...

Comment: I think it could really help someone who is getting in the game

Comment: Done! Hope it helps someone! :)